# Python Tkinter Calculator with shift function and Classes

Tags: python, class, tkinter, python-3.6

I am somewhat new to Python, and extremely new to class structures. I am trying to build a calculator GUI with buttons that insert a value into an Entry display. My calculator works without using class structures (the functional code is below), but I'm trying to make the same code work while incorporating the classes. My reason for doing this is to add a "shift" function that changes the values of text on the buttons, and what values (same as the text) they insert into the display. The values as you can see below are class variables, and in order to change the text on the buttons, the shift button is pressed which changes the value of the variables (I have gotten this to work in a non-tkinter file without buttons, etc). The problem is I am getting the GUI with an Entry and two Buttons (good) and '1' in the Entry. (not good) The buttons also don't do anything. Here is my code: (The one that works first)

```
from tkinter import *
import parser
import math


root = Tk()
root.title('Calculator')
displayb = Entry(root)
displayb.grid(row = 3, columnspan = 6, ipady = 7, ipadx = 100)

def display(e):
global i
i = len(displayb.get())
displayb.insert(i,e)

one = Button(root, text = '1', width = 10, height = 1, command = lambda : display(1))
one.grid(row = 4, column = 0)

root.mainloop()
```

New Code:

```
from tkinter import *
import parser



class Calc:
    text1 = '1'

    shft = 'shft1'
    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master = master

        self.displaya = Entry(master)
        self.displaya.grid(row = 1, columnspan = 6)
        self.one = Button(master, text = Calc.text1, command = self.display((Calc.text1)))
        self.one.grid(row = 4, column = 1)

        self.update = Button(master, text = Calc.shft, command = self.update((Calc.shft[4:5])))
        self.update.grid(row = 0, column = 0)


    def update(self, mode):
        if mode == 1:
            Calc.text1 = 'A'

            Calc.shft = 'shft2'
        else:
            Calc.text1 = '1'

            Calc.shft = 'shft1'

        return

    def display(self,e):

        i = len(self.displaya.get())
        self.displaya.insert(i,e)

        return
root = Tk()
calc = Calc(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Can you help me find a solution that makes my code work properly? Thanks

Edit: I attempted using `StringVar()` and `.set`, but on the interface, the shift button, instead of saying shft1 or even shft2, said "PY_VAR1". The one button said 1, but inserted "PY_VAR0" to the display. When pressed, the shift button raised this error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Users/ryanflynn/Classesmod.py", line 13, in <lambda>
    self.update_button = Button(master, text = self.shft, command = lambda: self.update(int(self.shft[4:5]))) # use int()
TypeError: 'StringVar' object is not subscriptable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Your code has few errors in it, here is a list of all of them and a modified version of your code:***

**1st:** Your button has the same name as one of your function, change it to a unique name.

**2nd:** Don't use the class's namespace unless it's necessary, use self instead.

**3rd:** You only need one set of brackets when calling a function, else it's redundant.

**4th:** Use `lambda` or `functools.partial` to set a command that has arguments.

**5th:** You can use `END`(since you did `from tkinter import *`, otherwise `tkinter.END`) to specify the ending instead of doing `len(self.displaya.get())`.

**6th:** `Calc.shft[4:5]` returns a `string` not an `int`. So in order to get your result, use `int(Calc.shft[4:5])`.

**7th:** I didn't see you using parser, so I don't see why you need it.

**8th:** Don't add a return at the end of a function that returns nothing, it's redundant. Since that's the default for all functions.

This is a modified(working) version of your code:

```
from tkinter import *

class Calc:
    def __init__(self,master):
        self.text1 = '1' # make them self's not Calc's
        self.shft = 'shft1'
        self.master = master

        self.displaya = Entry(master)
        self.displaya.grid(row = 1, columnspan = 6)
        self.one = Button(master, text = self.text1, command = lambda: self.display(self.text1)) # use lambda and single brackets
        self.one.grid(row = 4, column = 1)
        self.update_button = Button(master, text = self.shft, command = lambda: self.update(int(self.shft[4:5]))) # use int()
        self.update_button.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

    def update(self, mode):
        if mode == 1:
            self.text1 = 'A'

            self.shft = 'shft2'
        else:
            self.text1 = '1'

            self.shft = 'shft1'

    def display(self,e):
        self.displaya.insert(END,e) # use END instead

root = Tk()
calc = Calc(root)
root.mainloop()
```

This code does work but the button text shouldn't change

**EDIT:**
If you want to use string variable to make the text change, you will need a StringVar as well:

```
from tkinter import *

class Calc:
    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master = master

        self.displaya = Entry(master)
        self.displaya.grid(row = 1, columnspan = 6)
        self.text1 = StringVar(value = '1') # change to this
        self.shft = StringVar(value = 'shft1')
        self.one = Button(master, textvariable = self.text1, command = lambda: self.display(self.text1.get())) # Use .get()
        self.one.grid(row = 4, column = 1)
        self.update_button = Button(master, textvariable = self.shft, command = lambda: self.update(int(self.shft.get()[4:5]))) 
        self.update_button.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

    def update(self, mode):
        if mode == 1:
            self.text1.set('A') # set the variable

            self.shft.set('shft2')
        else:
            self.text1.set('1')

            self.shft.set('shft1')

    def display(self,e):
        self.displaya.insert(END,e) # use END instead

root = Tk()
calc = Calc(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `3rd: You only need one bracket when calling a function other wise it turns it to a tuple.` – it doesn't, if there are no commas inside the inner parentheses

Comment: @EliKorvigo Oh you're right, but still...that's not what you normally should write it as.... Thanks, Ill change it

Comment: @abccd this was very helpful, though I have some concerns/responses: 1) the code was functional, except the shifting part- which did not work. To elaborate, the button press did not cause button one to change its text or what it outputted. 2)Thank you for your tips on END, lambda, and int(), they were helpful! [side note I copy-pasted your code, so I got all of your corrections :)] Please help?

Comment: @abccd Correction: I did some tinkering; I changed `text = ` to `textvariable` and the function of the button/shift worked. However, there was no text on the actual one button.... Do you have a solution to this per chance?

Comment: @RyanFlynn Your question wasn't very clear on needing to change the text of the button so I didn't do anything about it therefore my button's text shouldn't change. How code should work though, after you pressed shift the 1 type A instead. I'll see what I can do, can't test right now

Comment: @abccd I was sure that would work. I tried just that, then tried adding `.set` but both raised the same error. What do you think?

Comment: If you actually have an error, I need to see it, please post your traceback

Comment: I saw the error you posted, your code if different from mine, so you should probably re copy-paste @RyanFlynn

Comment: I changed more than just StringVar

Comment: @abccd I missed the .get()'s! Thank you so much for your help I would +1 for every comment in this post if I could! This has been such an obstacle for me, so I am very grateful for your help!

Answer (score -1):

When you provide a function to the command argument, you need to provide the actual function, and not the result of calling the function. In other words, you can't have `()` on the end. One hacky way of handling this is to use `lambda` as you did earlier:

```
self.one = Button(master, text = Calc.text1, command = lambda: self.display((Calc.text1)))
```

A slightly less hacky way is to use `functools.partial`:

```
from functools import partial
# ...
self.one = Button(master, text = Calc.text1, command = partial(self.display, Calc.text1))
```

IMO the best way is to make a real method to use.

```
self.one = Button(master, text = Calc.text1, command = self.one_pushed)
# ...
def one_pushed(self):
    self.display(Calc.text1)
```

As a side note: tkinter will automatically calculate the end point for you if you pass 'end' as the position:

```
def display(self,e):
    self.displaya.insert('end',e)
```